# How to set on delete cascade on laravel-mongodb? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My delete method on controller is like this :

```
public function delete($id)
{
    MessageThread::destroy($id);
}
```

When the code executed, It success delete a record by id

But, the data on child table not deleted

Seems it must set on delete cascade

How can I set it?

I get the reference from here : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: Please show us a copy of your migration file.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I use mongodb. It does not need migration file

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm not familiar with Mongo

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, No problem